# Simple code - error driving me crazy... float to 2 bytes and back

Tags: java

Don't know how I finished school not being able to solve that little problem...

Following code produces unexpected output:

```
 public Color getPixel(int x, int y){
     return img.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y);
 }
 public float colorToHeight(Color c){
     int b =(int)(c.getBlue()*256);
     int r =(int)(c.getRed()*256*256);
     float h = (b+r)/2;
     h-=10000;
     return h;
 }
 public Color heightToColor(float h){
     h+=10000;
     h*=2;         
     double r= (int)(h/(256));
     double b = h-(r*256);
     return new Color(r/256,0,b/256,1f);
 }
public void debugPixel(int x, int z){

    System.out.println("test 424->Color:  "+heightToColor(424f));
    System.out.println("test Color->424:  "+colorToHeight(heightToColor(424f)));
    System.out.println("test Color->424->Color:  "+heightToColor(colorToHeight(heightToColor(424f))));
    System.out.println("check A: "+getPixel(x,z) + " Height: "+colorToHeight(getPixel(x,z)));
    System.out.println("check B: "+heightToColor(colorToHeight(getPixel(x,z))));
    System.out.println("check C: "+getPixel(x,z));
}
```

Output:

```
test 424->Color:  0x510070ff
test Color->424:  424.0
test Color->424->Color:  0x510070ff
check A: 0x5200cbff Height: 638.0
check B: 0x53001cff
check C: 0x5200cbff
```

I absolutely do not find the reason why [check B] != [check A]....Thanks!

Comment: Mind the `float <-> int` conversions, including the integral division `/`. It's quite **certain** the values won't be the same.

Comment: Which `Color` class is this? (I assume that this class does some clamping internally, and particularly causes the "red" component, which is likely out of range, to be clamped to [0.0, 1.0])

Comment: ...I think I found it....thought it was a stupid error, the correct int-to-float color is (int)Math.round((c.getBlue()*255)), found it inside Color class. Now the error is only 1 in my checks, so there will be some rounding error somewhere.

Comment: @SalkinD: No, your `int-to-float` was correct, or at least it didn't matter. The main error is realy the `float h = (b+r)/2;` line. Note that `(float) (1 + 2) / 2 == 1.0` and `1.0 * 2 == 2.0`, not the original `3.0`. The correct form is `float h = (b+r) / 2f`.

Comment: thanks @charlie, true that. Both things (255 instead of 256) and this int/int division, now it seems to work! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix the division to:

```
float h = (b + r) / 2f;
```

The original code performs the integer division first, then it converts to float, e.g. `(1 + 2) / 2 == 1.0`. After the fix, it evaluates as `(1 + 2) / 2.0 == 1.5`.

Thus, in your second test case the height should be:

```
red = 83
blue = 29
height = 638.5
```

While with the incorrect integer division:

```
height = 638.0 // 0.5 truncated off
red = 83
blue = 28 // while 29 is expected
```

Regarding the RGB bounds, if the `Color` class operates on the range `0..255`, take care when fixing that, since you need **2 distinct** constants — an RGB upper `LIMIT`, and the composition `SHIFT`:

```
private static final int LIMIT = 255;
private static final int SHIFT = 256; // or whatever > LIMIT, e.g. 1000

public float colorToHeight(Color c){
    int b = (int) Math.round(c.getBlue() * LIMIT);
    int r = (int) Math.round(c.getRed() * LIMIT);
    float h = (b + r * SHIFT) / 2f;
    h -= 10000;
    return h;
}

public Color heightToColor(float h){
    h += 10000;
    h *= 2;         
    double r = (int) (h / SHIFT);
    double b = h - (r * SHIFT);
    return new Color(r / LIMIT, 0, b / LIMIT, 1f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and the solution summary!

Answer (score 1):

It can't be sure at all that you get the same values, because the back & forth operations (`colorToHeight` or `heightToColor`) involve floating point operations, hence loss of precision which happens there.

You can rewrite your methods without using floating point, not even divisions since all can be done with shifts.

```
 public int colorToHeight(Color c){
     int b = c.getBlue()>>8;
     int r = c.getRed()>>16;
     int h = (b+r)/2;  // will be an integer, b and r are even
     h-=10000;
     return h;
 }
 public Color heightToColor(int h){
     h+=10000;
     h*=2;         
     int r= h>>8;
     int b = h-(r<<8);
     return new Color(r>>8,0,b>>8,1f);
 }
```

Comment: might i ask where you do see a comparison in his code?

Comment: thats no pointer, thats the toString method of Color object its 0xRRGGBBFF

Comment: still he´s not comparing any references in the given code. My guess he rather meant why the output after `check A` and `check B` differ.

Comment: ok, you're right. Looked like pointers. My last edit (which was: even if you fix the pointers, you'll have the next error) explains the rounding/floating point error hence the different values.

Comment: Answer updated and improved. I think the DV is no longer justified (it was justified before!)